# How to create a controller for a web service that uses another API

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, visual-studio-2012

I have reviewed Microsoft's tutorials on RESTFUL APIs and though I have a general understanding of how to create one, I'm at a lost on what exactly I should do.

Scenario: I have a separate Windows program that contains an API you can use written in C#. The program's job is to take a series of locations and return the mileage for those locations.  A DLL is used for this. I want to create a separate program (a RESTFUL web service in C#) that users can enter the values through a URL to obtain the mileage. The user can enter 2 or 20 locations maximum. There are also different types of mileages (modules) that can be used to return different types of mileages (the separate windows program handles this).

A location would have the following properties: ID, City, County, State, Zip Code.

I'm not exactly sure how to implement this. What should be in my class? What should be in my controller exactly? I was thinking I could have a single class that keeps track of all the properties of a location.

My biggest concern is also the controller. I'm not sure how to write it because I don't know how the URI should be. I think that a uri like /mileagetype/loc1/loc2/loc3/locx... might be too lengthy since the user can enter up to 20 locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create WCF Rest WebService to separate out the functionality from your app. Have a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services) for creating rest full webservices

Comment: Ok, I like this tutorial. It actually find it better than Microsoft's. haha. But, what if you are not creating a database? What if you are simply letting another API calculate the data?

Comment: Rest WebServices are stateless but if you don't want to use db then you can simple hard code values in your project.

Comment: Sorry to ask 21 questions... but would it be best to have the users' client run the URI as /calculate/mileagetype/loc1/loc2/loc3 or /calculate/mileagetype?loc=1&loc=2&loc=3...? Or neither? My concern is that the user can enter up to 20 locations at a time. Also, the tutorial seems to only show how to do the first one, not the latter.

Comment: for this particularly ,you can use get method from that article

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials like the one you provided that are more step by step with Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: How do you import the DLL and use the libraries in the service file?

Comment: If you have a dll and you would like to use it. You can reference it in your project by right clicking on references > click on Add Reference  and then browse for external dll then you can use it in  your service file.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Web Api 2.0 for this. Which is what it was intended for and is perfect for your use case.

[Getting started with Web Api 2.0 from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Your web API controller would contain just the end point, via URI's to the outside world and you would then go to your DLL for all of the actual logic.

For example on the client side they can pass you an entire complex JSON object that contains all of the properties you mentioned. On the server side (inside your Web API project) you can have a data transfer object with it's sole purpose is to bind to that JSON data coming from the client.

**A simple solution:**

On the Server your controller to handle the end-points can look like the below example for a very simple GET request.

```
public class MileageServiceController : ApiController
{

    // GET: api/MileageService?locations=100NewYork&locations=300NewJersey
    public string Get([FromUri] String[] locations)
    {
        String value = String.Empty;
        //TO DO - GOT TO DLL and get milage
        foreach (String loca in locations)
        {
            //you could go to your DLL here 
            //value += DLL.GetMilage(loca.ID, loca.City, etc...
            value += loca; //for testing
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

I wouldn't worry too much about how long the URL will get that isnt really a problem since
it will more than likely be generated by a client consumer which will be implemented in JavaScript or any other programming language.

**A more elegant solution:**

For the more elegant solution you can create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) on your server side API.
From there you can then pass complex objects from the client via a POST.

Your DTO can look like this:

```
public class Location
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
    public string County {get; set;}
    public string State {get; set;}
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Your Controller can look like this:

```
    // POST: api/MileageService - accept an array of location DTO's
    public void Post([FromBody]Location[] locations)
    {
        //Go to DLL and figure out milage for each DTO
    }
```

[More on complex types and web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1)

Comment: Do you know how to add the DLL and use it in the code?

Comment: Yes of course. You add it like any other DLL, inside visual studio after you create your web api project go to references and right click add it. Then inside your controller add a using statement for its namespace. Then find the functions you need from it.